# running python program in from website

Tags: python, web

Hullo, I've recently gotten into web dev and I have a text adventure game 
written in Python that I'd like to be make available and playable from my website (locally stored for now, and I'm using Bootstrap). How would I go about that?

Comment: Use something like http://www.skulpt.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Python my suggestion would be to get something like Django. You should be able to copy-paste some of the bits into your new web app that way.

There's a website that explains how it works http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/

And if you're more of a book kinda person, you can buy this one on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Django-Development-Sanjeev-Jaiswal/dp/1783984406/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1447426331&sr=1-6&keywords=Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783984406)

There are more books on the subject, so I suggest you check out the reviews for them before actually buying a book on the subject :-)